# Is this a selenium issue or website issue?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have made a list of all links present on the given webpage. It is including spaces and considering them links (when I print its length). I cannot seem to figure out what's happening. Is this selenium issue, webpage issue or am I doing it wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\D-Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")
print(len(links))

for link in links:
    print(link.text)
```

The output of the length part is:
171

The link.text output displays the links but with a lot of spaces. I checked and the len(links) is also considering these spaces.

Comment: This probably not a web site issue or selenium issue. Just trim the whitespace from the beginning and end of the text.

Comment: You're getting the text, not the href... is that what you really wanted here?

Comment: @pcalkins nope. I need the links... how should I proceed?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Trim the workspace? whats that?

Comment: I think you want: link.get_attribute("href")

Comment: @pcalkins I see... I will read on how to exactly implement that. Thank you. And if possible, I would like to know where selenium and python are used at an industrial level